# SQL Server : lookup of 1000 records too slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I ran into a performance problem with query like this:

```
select a, b, c 
from something 
where key in (thousand keys)
```

It takes around 5 seconds to complete and in plan I see most expensive operation key lookup.

`Key` is the primary clustered key, table has 200'000 records and 15 fixed size columns.

When I didn't clear cache with `dbcc` options it works fast.

Please, help to fix or diagnose.

Comment: Hint : **`Index`**

Comment: First of all: is the an **index** on your `key` column? If not - add one. Also: I'd recommend inserting those "thousand keys" into a temp table and then do a proper `INNER JOIN` between your table `something` and that temp table

Comment: Yes it primary clustered key, i also tryed joins it makes the same execution plan

Comment: Post the execution plan. Key lookup on clustered index looks suspicions.